# Transformation of Bernoulli r.v.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Bern}(1/2)$ and let $a$ and $b$ be constants with $a < b$. Find a simple transformation of $X$ that yields a r.v. that equals $a$ with probability $1 - p$ and equals b with probability $p$.

I'm not sure how to approach it. I can solve the opposite, given a $Bern(p)$ I can generate $a$ and $b$ with equal probabilities but I'm somehow blocked on the above.

I'd appreciate some hints.

Comment: How can you solve the opposite problem?

Comment: Imagine having a fair coin, with probability of heads $p$, $0$ below denotes tail and 1 denotes heads. 

$0 0 = (1-p)^2$,
$0 1 = p(1-p)$,
$1 0 = p(1-p)$,
$1 1 = p^2$

Now event $head-head$ and $tail-tail$  has the same probability with $head-tail$ and $tail-head$ equal to $p^2(1-p)^2$. If you generate a value that's not falling into any of the two categories, you throw it away and sample again, regardless of the value of p the values will be generated with probability $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: You are using **multiple** i.i.d. Bernoulli variables, which completely changes the question.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: The only way to answer the question is to change the question. Rather than changing the question to allow additional sources of randomness, why not just change to assume $p=1/2$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. If I assume, p is $\frac{1}{2}$ I can have a linear transformation $Y = bX + a(1-X) = a + (b-a)X$ where $X ~ Bern(\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: Yes. The question as asked can only be solved when $p \in \{0,1/2,1\}$. Otherwise, you would need to change the question by allowing additional sources of randomness.